# Optimize $\max _{x_1,x_2,...,x_N} N , \text{ s.t.} \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i) \le a$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization

$Is there general theory for solving optimization problem of the following kind

\begin{align}
&\max _{x_1,x_2,...,x_N} N \\
\text{ s.t.}& \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i) \le a\\
&\sum_{i=1}^N g(x_i) \le b\\
& \sum_{i=1}^N x_i  \le c
\end{align}

where $f()$ and $g()$ are given convex, non-negative functions.
The 'weird' property of this problem is that we have to optimize over the argument of the summation. 
At this stage I am looking at reference and examples.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the functions $f$ and $g$ convex? If not, please remove the "convex-optimization" tag. And is there any other information about $f$, $g$, and $x$ you can share? It matters.

Comment: Yes, they are. I will add. But even then is it still a convex optimization problem?

Comment: Oh no, it's definitely not convex. But it might be quasiconvex. Again, is there anything else you can say about $f$, $g$, and $x$? For instance, are they nonnegative? Monotonic?

Comment: I guess I can add non-negativity.  Have you seen a problem like that in some context before? Also, for simplicity we can just look at the case when there is no $g$.

Comment: No, I haven't. But Boby, come on, details like convexity and non-negativity *matter*. They can spell the difference between being able to solve the problem efficiently and not being able to solve it at all. When you ask a question here you need to supply *all* the information about the problem you have.

Comment: @Michael Thank you. I know what you mean. I will try to be more clear next time. In my case I also have several choices of $f$ and $g$. For example, $f$ can be concave and $g$ convex. I didn't want to give so many details and wanted to see whether such problems appeared somewhere before or how to at least approach a simple case. But you are absolutely right I should have include that f and g are non-negative, for example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The obvious guess is going to be that the optimal solution will take the form $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_N$ for some $N$.  Thus, this suggests solving the following optimization problem:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{maximize } \; &N\\
\text{subject to } \; &N f(x) \le a, N g(x) \le b, Nx \le c
\end{align*}$$

where $x$ ranges over $\mathbb{R}$ and $N$ ranges over $\mathbb{N}$.  Now you have only a two-dimensional optimization problem.

For instance, you could iterate over $N=1,2,3,\dots$ and for each fixed $N$, search for $x \in [-\infty,c/N]$ such that  $f(x) \le a/N$ and $g(x) \le b/N$.  Depending on the form of $f,g$, this might be feasible to solve.

If this is possible, you could speed it up by using bisection search to find the largest such $N$ (i.e., start by iterating over $N=1,2,4,8,16,\dots$; then when you find $N_0,N_1$ such that $N_0$ is feasible and $N_1$ isn't feasible, use binary search to find the largest $N$ such that $N_0 \le N < N_1$ and $N$ is feasible).

Better yet, define

$$h(x) = \max(f(x)/a, g(x)/b, x/c).$$

You can verify that $N,x$ is a feasible solution if and only if $h(x) \le 1/N$.  Thus, to maximize $N$, it suffices to find $x^*$ that minimizes $h(x)$, and take $N=\lfloor 1/h(x^*) \rfloor$.  Since $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a unidimensional function, minimizing $h(x)$ might be feasible via a number of methods, depending on the specific properties of of $f,g$.